# Does LINQ To Object do any tuning internally?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I wonder how LINQ to Objects determines the best way to query in a collection ?

I mean, is there any difference (in how LINQ works internally) between the following LINQ queries:

```
var lst1 = ListOfComplexClass.Where(p => p.StrValue == "Whatever")
                             .Select(p => p.StrValue);
```

And

```
var lst2 = ListOfComplexClass.Select(p => p.StrValue)
                             .Where(p => p == "Whatever");
```

For example, will the first one filter the collection of `ListOfComplexClass` and then get the `StrValue` property?
Or will it do some tuning and execute the `Select` first and then filter the returned collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example.. will the first one filter the collection of ListOfComplexClass and then get the StrValue property? Or it'll make some maybe tunning and execute the Select first and then filter the returned collection?

(I am assuming that you meant `p => p.StrValue` in the `Select` in the first one.)

Actually, it's more subtle than that.

Let us say that you take an enumerator on the first one.

```
var lst1 = ListOfComplexClass.Where(p => p.StrValue == "Whatever")
                             .Select(p => p.StrValue);
var e = lst1.GetEnumerator();
```

When you call `e.MoveNext()`, what will happen is that `Select` will call `MoveNext()` on an iterator of `ListOfComplexClass.Where(p => p.StrValue == "Whatever")` which will call `MoveNext()` an iterator of `ListOfComplexClass` until it finds an element `p` with `p.StrValue == "Whatever"`. Then, the projected result of this `p` will be returned as `e.Current`.

Now let us consider the second one. Let us say that you take an enumerator of it.

```
var lst2 = ListOfComplexClass.Select(p => p.StrValue)
                             .Where(p => p == "Whatever");
var e = lst2.GetEnumerator();
```

When you call `e.MoveNext()`, `Where` will call `MoveNext()` on an iterator of `ListOfComplexClass.Select(p => p.StrValue)` until it finds an element `p` with `p == "Whatever"`. Of course, calling `MoveNext()` on an iterator of `ListOfComplexClass.Select(p => p.StrValue)` will call `MoveNext()` on an iterator of `ListOfComplexClass` and return the projection of `Current` for that iterator.

Jon Skeet has a good analogy which I'll steal here. Imagine a deck of cards in random order. Imagine the queries

```
var suits = deck.Where(c => c.Suit == Suit.Diamond || c.Suit == Suit.Heart)
                .Select(c => c.Suit)
```

and

```
var suits = deck.Select(c => c.Suit)
                .Where(c => c == Suit.Diamond || c == Suit.Heart);
```

Now imagine consuming the result of the first query. It goes like this.

`Select` asks `Where` for a card.

`Where` asks `deck` for a card.

*`Where` checks the suit of the card.

If the suit of the card is a diamond or a heart, it returns the card to the `Select` and `Select` projects the card to its suit and returns it.

If the suit of the card is not a diamond or a heart, `Where` asks for another card from deck and loops back to *.

The second query goes like this.

`Where` asks `Select` for a suit.

`Select` asks `deck` for a card.

`deck` returns a card to Select.

`Select` projects the card to its suit.

*`Where` checks the suit from the `Select`.

If the suit is a diamond or a heart, `Where` returns the suit.

If the suit is not a diamond or a heart, `Where` asks `Select` for another suit and loops back to *.

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder that does LINQ to Object look for the best way to query in a collection ?

No, it couldn't. There is no 'engine' here. The calls are working on each others output in a direct chain. If the second is faster than that is an optimization you will have to make.

Maybe that Linq-to-SQL or Linq-to-Entities (IQueryable) could optimize something, but not Linq-to-Objects.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case it doesn't matter. You are projecting a string directly so no new object is created and you still have just one comparison. On the other hand there can be cases (projecting into another type) where it could matter. I don't believe LINQ will try to optimize away the projections because they may contain side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to objects doesn't use expressions like linq to sql, so there is no place for optimization like that - each linq command returns another enumerable or value. There might be some optimization when using `from .. in .. where .. select ..` syntaxe by compiler, but I wouldn't expect anything complicated either. In your example using `where` first should be *slightly* faster (in theory at least), because of transition between `where` and `select` will be already filtered, but I don't think we can even measure such difference since it is really just passing values between caller and callee. However if you would be somehow transforming value you are selecting, difference would be noticable because you would be creating new object on already filtered collection.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you present there is no difference.

But if you put a ToList to ToArray somewhere there, it could make a difference.

LINQ to Objects, as LINQ to SQL, is still uses lazy execution, even though it's just working on in memory objects.

This is because LINQ extensions on IEnumerable use Expression Trees. This means you LINQ expressions are only executed when there is a need to.

usually if you're chaining IEnumerable extensions then it won't make a difference. however if you need to change types half way, or call something like ToList then that will alter the order of execution.

Comment: Thanks, I'm of course discussing the tuning when I use the collection by loop through it or return it as a list.